# How can I pass JavaScript values to another PHP page using an HTML form?

Tags: php, javascript, html, geolocation, submit

I have spent more than 2 months trying to solve this coding problem. First of all I know JavaScript runs on the client side and PHP runs on server.

I have two PHP pages (index23.php and index24.php), both use HTML/PHP and JS.

I'm using the HTML5 geolocation API:

```
<body onload="getLocation()">

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
    x.innerHTML= "+" + position.coords.latitude + "+" + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>
```

I can see the geocode values on my current PHP page (index23.php). Then I click an HTML form button and the browser goes to another page (index24.php).

How can I pass the JavaScript values on the first PHP page to the second PHP page using the submit button on the form?

This is my form:

```
<form id="searchbox" action="index24.php" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Type here"/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search"></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index23.php:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLocation(){
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    if (navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{
        x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position){
    var x = document.getElementById("demo"),latitude=document.getElementById("latitude"),longitude=document.getElementById("longitude");
    x.innerHTML="+" + position.coords.latitude + "+" + position.coords.longitude;
    latitude.value = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude.value = position.coords.longitude;
}

</script>

</head>
<body onload="getLocation()">

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <form id="searchbox" action="index24.php" method="get">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Type here"/>
    <input name="latitude" id="latitude" type="hidden">
    <input name="longitude" id="longitude" type="hidden">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search"></form>
</body></html>
```

index24.php

```
$latitude = $_GET['latitude'];
$longitude = $_GET['longitude'];
```

Comment: you would have to switch over to `$_POST` method for it to not show in the URL

Answer (score 6):

what you need to do is make a input type hidden and send value through it

```
<input name="bla"  type="hidden" value="blabla">
```

also html is not server side .. only php is. i hope  image below  explain

[image]

<sub><sub>[image source](http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson1.php)</sub></sub>

Comment: like for the picture :D

Answer (score 0):

You can add the values to the form dynamically when you get the coordinates.

```
<form id="searchbox" action="index24.php" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Type here"/>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
<input name="latitude" type="hidden" id="latitude" value="" />
<input name="longitude" type="hidden" id="longitude" value="" />
</form>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
{
  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
}
function showPosition(position)
{
  document.getElementById('latitude').value = position.coords.latitude;
  document.getElementById('longitude').value = position.coords.longitude;
  x.innerHTML="+" + position.coords.latitude + "+" + position.coords.longitude;    
}
</script>
```